# Scala change parameters of function defined in trait

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traits, companion-object

Because I didn't find a solution to my problem anywhere, I think I might be thinking into a very wrong direction.

Here's my problem:
I have a trait A and another trait B and companion objects AB1, AB2, AB3 and so on. The singleton objects extend trait A and the classes extend trait B. Many objects of those classes are in a list.

On these objects I want to use functions defined in the corresponding singleton object which take objects of the same class as the singleton object is.

This an example for the traits:

```
trait A {
    def compare(firstB: B, secondB: B) : Int
}

trait B {}
```

And the companion objects:

```
class AB1(val variable: Int) extends B {}

object AB1 extends A {
    def apply(list: List[Int]): Option[AB1] = {
        if(list.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) < 10 && list.nonEmpty)
            some(new AB1(list.head))
        else
            null
    }
    override def compare(ab11: AB1, ab12: AB1): Int = {
        if(ab11 > ab12) 
            1
        else if(ab11 > ab12) 
            -1
        else 
            0
    }
}
```

and

```
class AB2(val variable1: Int, val variable2: Int) extends B {}

object AB2 extends A {
    def apply(list: List[Int]): Option[AB1] = {
        if(list.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) < 20 && list.length >= 2)
            some(new AB1(list.head, list.tail.head))
        else
            null
    }
    override def compare(ab21: AB2, ab22: AB2): Int = {
        if(ab11 > ab12) 
            10
        else if(ab11 > ab12) 
            -10
        else 
            0
    }
}
```

So I've already filtered the *some* objects and put the "real" objects into a list, let's call it bList. On every element of the list I want to call the compare function.

I think it would look something like this:

```
val bList: List[B]
val a = getA(bList.head) // getA should be a function that returns the companion object of a class
a.compare(bList.head, bList.tail.head)
```

On my way I encountered two problems:

1. `b.getClass` does not equal `AB1.getClass` when b is an object the class AB1. But this is not my main problem. I found a solution using String comparison, which really is not pretty, but for now, it works.
2. The `compare` function has to be defined in the trait, because otherwise it can't be casted on any singleton object that extends trait A. But I find no way to define the function with parameters of a variable type.

I really hope you can help me with this problem!

**EDIT**: Now I see that I've forgotten to mention something:

I think that I have to go a bit deeper into what I am trying to do to make you understand my problem:

I have a `List[List[C]]`. A List of those `C`'s may be capable of creating an AB1 object with it but maybe AB2, or maybe AB3 and so on. So I have

```
val c: List[C] = (C1, C2, C4)
val aList: List[A] = (AB1, AB2, AB3, ...)
val bestB: B = (for{
    element <- aList
} yield element  (c)).flatten.head   // Because the List aList is ordered: AB1 is the best case, AB2 the second best and so on.
```

I do that for every List[C] out of the List[List[C]]. So in the end I may have a `List[B] = (AB3, AB1, AB2, AB1)` (for example). From this list I want to get the "best" `B`s according to the order of `aList` at first - then i get `List[B] = (AB1, AB1)`. These two `AB1`'s I want to compare and then put the "better" Element (according to the compare function of the corresponding object) or both into a new list. This is want I want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @SimonDose, Many things here...
First, you shouldn't be using null, especially if you're already using Option.
Second, `AB1.getClass` is different to `b.getClass`, because AB1 being an object has its own class _(even if its a companion object)_.
Third, You shouldn't be checking classes instances, instead use pattern matching, thats more idiomatic in Scala.
Finally, Could you make your question more clear, I have read it three times but can't understand exactly what is your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is a little confusing. It feels like it's something to do with the Ordered trait, but unclear what your objectives are. Why use `object` rather than `case classes` ?

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez
Thank you for your answer. I edited the question to make it clearer what my problem exactly is. I understand that AB1 and b are different classes. But how could I compare them using pattern matching?

Comment: @Andy Hayden
Because of static functions and variables that I use, I thought objects were the right choice

Comment: @SimonDose Can't you have the best of both with case class + companion object?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm still confused with what is your root problem. But I will try to answer what I understood.

First, if you want to change the type of the arguments when overriding a function from a trait. Then, the answer is **you can't!** - Because that would break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

But you can achieve what you want with a [Type Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) .

```
trait B {}

trait BComparator[Bi <: B] {
  def compare(firstB: Bi, secondB: Bi): Int
}
```

Now if you want a way to dynamically obtain the right instance of the `BComparator` for your sub-classes you could make those instances as implicit values in their companion objects.

```
class B1 extends B {}
object B1 {
  implicit val B1Comparator: BComparator[B1] = new BComparator[B1] {
    override def compare(firstB: B1, secondB: B2): Int = ???
  }
}
```

Now, given b11 and b12 as instances of B1 you could just write

```
implicitly[BComparator[B1]].compare(b11, b12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use implicit `Comparator`:

```
trait B
case class AB1(variable: Int) extends B
case class AB2(variable1: Int, variable2: Int) extends B

implicit object AB1Comparator extends Comparator[AB1] {
  override def compare(o1: AB1, o2: AB1): Int = java.lang.Integer.compare(o1.variable, o2.variable)
}

implicit object AB2Comparator extends Comparator[AB2] {
  override def compare(o1: AB2, o2: AB2): Int = java.lang.Integer.compare(o1.variable1, o2.variable1) match {
    case 0 => java.lang.Integer.compare(o1.variable2, o2.variable2)
    case other => other
  }
}

def compare[A](obj1: A, obj2: A)(implicit comparator: Comparator[A]) = {
  comparator.compare(obj1, obj2)
}

val ab1List = List(AB1(1), AB1(2), AB1(3))
val ab1Compare = compare(ab1List.head, ab1List.tail.head)

val ab2List = List(AB2(1, 1), AB2(1, 1), AB2(1, 3))
val ab2Compare = compare(ab2List.head, ab2List.tail.head)
```

Or if you want to sort list you should use `Ordering`:

```
trait B
case class AB1(variable: Int) extends B

implicit object AB1Ordering extends Ordering[AB1] {
  override def compare(o1: AB1, o2: AB1): Int = java.lang.Integer.compare(o1.variable, o2.variable)
}
val ab1List = List(AB1(1), AB1(2), AB1(3))
val ab1ListSorted = ab1List.sorted
```